# Seasons pass within a day. Where am I?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Seasons pass within a day and the sun moves in reverse. I am in love with this place. Where am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are

> on Venus

Where

> the Sun goes in the opposite direction across the sky as compared to Earth because the rotation of Venus is opposite that of earth

And

> One Venus year = 1.92 Venus days, so about 2 seasons per day.

And

> You love it.... Venus.  Goddess of love

Comment: Correct and well done!

Comment: ..that's not how seasons work.

Comment: It would have been too obvious if I used year

Answer (score 1):

Seasons pass within a day

> A "day" , if counted from one sunrise to the next one, lasts 12 months on both poles. This is of course the same period of time it takes for the seasons to cycle.

and the sun moves in reverse.

> Assuming we're used to the sun moving clockwise across the sky as it does in the northern hemisphere. The reverse happens on the other side of the globe where the sun moves anticlockwise.

I am in love with this place. Where am I?

> You're on the **South Pole**? Stay warm!